# python+flask：reported error at python console

Tags: python-3.x, traceback

run a demo code to test the python & flask, the code show as below:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhsev.png)

the error message is :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQQTv.png)

check the pycharm si 2022.2.3;
python is 3.10
the setting like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leH4o.png)

the code can be run,it should be python issue,how can i fix it?

Comment: Your python interpreter path differs between those screenshots, maybe wsgi is not found, because you are running your project with an unrelated python interpreter?

Comment: Please do not post code as picture, so other people with the same problem can find the answer faster. Read the Hot to ask for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask